# Python Variable - name '' is not defined

Tags: python, variables, global

Hello I am a newbie to Python.

Declaration of variables is frustrating as it should be easy but I have such hard time to make this work..
I've read other stackoverflow questions and apparently there is no such thing as initialization in Python and I need keyword: global before variable to use it in different places..

```
 @app.route('/calculate', methods = ['GET'])      

 def calculate(): 
      # get value from html by request.args.get()
```

Option1.

```
   global newWeightForSecondItem
   if weightT1 != weightT2:
       newWeightForSecondItem = convert(weightT1, weightT2, weight2)
```

Option 2.

```
   if weightT1 != weightT2:
       global newWeightForSecondItem = convert(weightT1, weightT2, weight2)
```

Neither works..
When I do such calculation below, I get an error: NameError: name 'newWeightForSecondItem' is not defined.

```
   if discountT2 == "percentage":
       finalPrice2 = float((float(price2) - (float(price2) * float(discount2))) / newWeightForSecondItem)
   elif discountT2 == "dollar":
       finalPrice2 = float((float(price2) - float(discount2)) / newWeightForSecondItem)


def convert(weightT1, weightT2, weight2):
   # converting calculation here 

return weight2


 # main method
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.debug = True
     app.run()
```

Comment: There is no variable declaration in Python, so that likely explains why you are finding it difficult.

Comment: Can you post a more complete set of your code... this is a scoping issue and you've shown us none of your scope.

Comment: @TemporalWolf based on your advice, I've added the overall code. Thank you.

Comment: Have you called `calculate()` **before** you got the NameError? If not 
 `newWeightForSecondItem` would never have been initialized. To be on the safe side you can init `newWeightForSecondItem` outside of the function.

Comment: @DahliaSR yes. calculate() is called first.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot time to figure out why I got this error. 
NameError: name 'newWeightForSecondItem' is not defined.

However, that was not the main issue. I forgot to convert string to float datatype for newWeightForSecondItem. After I changed it to float(newWeightForSecondItem), it works. This was a very easy mistake and I think python's error was not very helpful.

Thank you for all the comments, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have newWeightForSecondItem as a global variable perhaps you can try this:

```
 newWeightForSecondItem = None

 @app.route('/calculate', methods = ['GET'])      
 def calculate():
     global newWeightForSecondItem
     if weightT1 != weightT2:
         newWeightForSecondItem = convert(weightT1, weightT2, weight2)
```

You declare/initialize the global variable, and then you can use it inside the function

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't get the same error anymore but now I get NonType in the calculation..

Comment: Instead of newWeightForSecondItem = None, you should initialize the value before using it. maybe set it to newWeightForSecondItem = 0.

Comment: @GabrielFalcones which will yield a `ZeroDivisionError`, because he's calling it before assigning to it.

Comment: @GabrielFalcones yes.. TemporalWolf is correct. I get ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: You get that error because you are calling that variable as the denominator of a division, in that case you shouldnt initialize the variable with 0, but with a different number.